# How to verify this relationship between area under the graph and the preimage?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Define $h : \mathbb{R} \to [0, \infty)$,

Let $H = \{(x,y)| 0 \leq y \leq h(x)\}$ be the area under the graph (including the boundary)

> I wish to show the following is true:
>
> $$H = \bigcup_{c>0} h^{-1}[c,\infty) \times [0, c]$$

Attempt:

($\subseteq$) Let $(x,y) \in H$, then $0 \leq y \leq h(x)$, then $h^{-1}[y,\infty) \times [0, y] \subseteq h^{-1}[c,\infty) \times [0, c] \quad \forall y,c \in \mathbb{R}$, so $H \subseteq \bigcup_{c>0} h^{-1}[c,\infty) \times [0, c]$

($\supseteq$)  Not sure...

Comment: One proves that a union of sets is contained in $H$ by showing that each individual set in the union is contained in $H$. So fix $c>0$ ... can you prove that $h^{-1}[c,\infty) \times [0,c] \subseteq H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h = 0$ (so the constant function), then $h^{-1}[c,\infty)] = \emptyset$ for all $c > 0$, as no $x$ has $h(x) \ge c > 0$. And then the product set is empty too and we'd get $H = \emptyset$ which is false, as $H = X \times \{0\}$. So we should have a union for all $c \ge 0$ not just $c > 0$. The rest of the post assumes this change.

Now the proof from left to right should be written a bit differently. Pick $(x,y) \in H$, so $0 \le y \le h(x)$, where $x,y$ are fixed. Pick $c = y$, which is now OK, as $y \in [0,\infty)$, so $c \ge 0$. Then $x \in h^{-1}[[c,\infty)]$, as $h(x) \ge y = c$ and $y \in [0,c]$, as $c = y$. So $(x,y)$ is in the union, as we have a specific (!) $c$ such that $(x,y)$ is in the right hand side for that $c$.

Right to left is quite similar. If $(x,y)$ is in the union, there is a specific fixed $c$ (for that pair) such that $(x,y) \in h^{-1}[[c,\infty)] \times [0,c]$.

The latter means that $x \in h^{-1}[[c,\infty)]$ and $y \in [0,c]$. So we have
$h(x) \in [c,\infty)$ (so $h(x) \ge c$) and $0 \le y \le c$, and so combining we get $0 \le y \le c \le h(x)$ which means that $(x,y) \in H$.

Comment: Thank you. This is amazing. Would the proof be different if the closed interval $[0, c]$ was half closed i.e. $[0, c)$ and $H$ is taken as $\{(x,y)|0\leq y < h(x)\}$?

Comment: If $h(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in that case? Have you tried the change yourself?